# Since my queryset is a "string query", how can I execute it?

Tags: django, django-models, memcached, django-views

I am using memcached in Django, but in some cases I need to use low-level cache api. So I had an idea to create a function to make things easy:

```
def store_cache(key,query,time):

   if cache.get(key):
      return cache.get(key)
  else:
      result = **# execute query that was passed in parameter #** 
      cache.set(key,result,time)
      return result
```

This function would be called something like:

```
store_cache("my_key", "MyUser.get.objects.all.filter(x = y)", 500)
```

My question... Since my queryset is a "string query", how can I execute it inside my function store_cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best way to design that API, because what you're asking for is the use of `eval()`, and you don't really want that because `eval()` is evil and coding an application around eval isn't safe.

The better approach would be this:

```
def myobject_cache(key, query, time):

   data = cache.get(key)
   if data:
      return data
  else:
      result = list(CustomObjectThatHoldsLotsOfQuerySets.get(query))
      cache.set(key, result, time)
      return result

class CustomObjectThatHoldsLotsOfQuerySets(object):
    def get(key):
        if key == "MyObject":
            return MyObject.objects.filter(x=y)
        #do other stuff here
```